# Genetic Algorithm Approximating Images with Polygons - Fitness Calculating

Tags: genetic-algorithm

So I'm implementing GA. And I've got an array of polygons for a generation. Every polygon has a `color` and some `point`s.
I'm calculating the fitness right now like this:

`Paint the polygons onto a 200x200 view` -> `Get a snapshot of the view` -> `Get 40000 pixel data from the snapshot` -> `Compare the 40000 pixel data with the target image pixel data and returns the fitness`

This is actually a very bad implement because UI rendering takes a lot of time.
What better method can I use for the fitness calculating? How do I get 40000 pixel data from an a array of polygons? Because you know, I cant get an exact RGBA pixel data at an exact coordinate from that array.

Comment: Maybe you can sample -- compare the value at 1000 randomly chosen points rather than all 40,000. Bring more points into play as your polygons evolve. Simple algebra (equations and linear inequalities involving various lines) should be able to tell you where a given edge falls on a 200x200 coordinate system.

Comment: I think I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yep, sampling will work. A simple way to do this is to simply render a smaller image (say 20x20). You can increase the size as the images evolve later.